# What is the role of the -signkey option in openssl-req?

Tags: linux, openssl

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 1024
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -out server.crt -signkey server.key -days 3650
```

This is a popular command for generating self-signed SSL certificates using OpenSSL.

What confuses me is the `-signkey` parameter in the third command line, what is the use of this option? I don't see it in `openssl req -help`.

Can anyone answer it please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you looking at `req`'s help? The third line is using `x509` command:

```
]$ openssl x509 -help
...
 -signkey infile       Self sign cert with arg
```

So it is the key with which you self-sign the certificate.